# xcom_push always throws Invalid utf8mb4 character string Warning - Airflow 1.10.9

Tags: mysql, airflow

No matter what I push using xcom_push() it always throws:

`WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:588: Warning (1300, "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '800358'") cursor.execute(statement, parameters)`

I know it's the xcom_push() throwing the error because if I comment out all the xcom_pushes then the warning goes away.  I tried a single xcom_push() with static text and I still get the error.

`task_instance.xcom_push(key="test", value="test")`

My backend is a MySql database v8.0.19.  Any suggestions to fix?

Edit: database was created like so:

`CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Edit 2: I tried recreating the database like below, but it still gives the same warning:

`CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: Just to be clear, yes it is always '800358' no matter what I actually push

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didn't catch airflow 1.10.x requires MySql 5.7.  I changed the backend database and the warning went away.